# android-java error

Tags: java, android

i am trying a develop a application..following is a snippet

```
class metro_nodes {
public String station;
public GeoPoint point; }

public class mainscreen extends MapActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

MapController controller;
double latitude,longitude;
LocationManager loc;
Location lastknownloc;
LocationListener loclistener;
List<GeoPoint> geopoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
MapView mapView;
private LinkedList<metro_nodes> station_location = new LinkedList<metro_nodes>();
metro_nodes anand_nagar;
anand_nagar.station = "anand_nagar";
    }
```

now in the second last line its giving -"Syntax error on token "station", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token"

if i put curly braces around this statement then error get removed..but then i get java lang null pointer exception...
whats the problm ??

Comment: You should probably learn some basic java before attempting to make an app that involves something this complicated. It will make it a lot easier on yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the code that gives you the syntax error...but I'm guessing you're getting the null pointer exception because you never initialized any "metro_nodes" objects.

For example:

```
// This is a helper class
class MetroNode {
  public String station;
  public GeoPoint point; 

  public MetroNode (String station, GeoPoint point) {
    this.station = station;
    this.point = point;
  }
}

// This is the module's main class
public class MainScreen extends MapActivity {

  // This is public and private data for each class instance
  private LinkedList<MetroNode> station_location = null;

  // This is the activity's initialization
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    station_locations = new LinkedList<MetroNode>();
    MetroNode metroNode = new MetroNode ("anand_nagar", new GeoPoint (1.00, 2.00));
    station_locations.add (metroNode);
  ...
```

Comment: you should not create the constructor of Activity... use onCreate...

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh: point well taken - I didn't notice the class happened to be an Android "activity".  My point was that *every* object needs to be "created" (it doesn't just happen "by magic"), and that every class needs some initialization method (usually, a constructor).  I think the OP's question is more "Java 101" than about Android programing per se.  IMHO...

Comment: thanks for your replies...a very silly mistake on my part...

Answer (score 1):

You have class field declarations there, and the second last line is a statement that does not belong in the variable declaration section - has to be done as part of a method/constructor.

By enclosing it in curly braces you are actually creating a class initialization block, however trying to access anand_nagar variable before you assigned any instance to it results in NPE. Austin is right - seems you are missing some basic Java programming knowledge, so perhaps you should start with some Java tutorial first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Null Pointer expiation is as you have not crated the instance of  metro_nodes for  variable anand_nagar using new

```
metro_nodes anand_nagar;
anand_nagar = new metro_nodes();//<----------------need this line to avoid NPE 
anand_nagar.station = "anand_nagar";
```

and Please also follow standards like Class name should be like MetroNode in java.....

```
public class MainScreen extends MapActivity {


    private MapController mController;
    private double mLatitude,mLongitude;
    private LocationManager mLoc;
    private Location mLastknownloc;
    private LocationListener mLoclistener;

    private MapView mMapView;
    private LinkedList<MetroNode> mStationLocations;
    MetroNode mAnandNagar;


    //in general we use cunstructor for initliaztion but in android we usesonCreate
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ..other code ..............

        List<GeoPoint> geoPoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
        mStationLocations = new LinkedList<MetroNode>();
        mAnandNagar = new MetroNode();
        mAnandNagar.setStation("anand_nagar");
    }
}

class MetroNode {
    private  String station;
    private  GeoPoint point;

    public MetroNode(){
        super();    
    }

    public MetroNode(String station, GeoPoint point) {
        super();
        this.station = station;
        this.point = point;
    }

    public String getStation() {
        return station;
    }
    public void setStation(String station) {
        this.station = station;
    }
    public GeoPoint getPoint() {
        return point;
    }
    public void setPoint(GeoPoint point) {
        this.point = point;
    }




}
```

Comment: Don't you think that thirty lines, four methods, two constructors and calling "super()" (when there isn't even have a base class) is just a wee bit excessive for what's essentially a two-field data structure?

Comment: thanks for your replies...a very silly mistake on my part...